# Laravel 5 extendable entities, how to?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

So, let's say I have basic `Document` with `title`, `author`,`link_to_file` properties and `belongsToMany(Document)` and `hasMany(Document)` recursive parent-child relations.

Now I want to extend my `Document` into, let's say, 3 (or more) types: `Letter`,`Report` and `Contract`, which can have their own unique properties (e.g. `Letter` has `sender` and `recepient`, `Contract` can have a some fields like `valid_until` and such) in the addition to inherited ones.

And I want them all to still have `title` property (inherited from `Document`) and be able to have child-parent relations with eachother (`Contract` can be parent of `Letter`, which can be parent of another `Contract`, which can be parent of `Report`... etc.) without hardcoding it.

How do I implement this in laravel? 
I mean the extending thing. I'm aware of the fact that I can implement `Letter`,`Report` and `Contract` as separate entities without having an ancestor class/entity.

**UPD:** If I were doing it from scratch (no frameworks involved), I would've probably ended with following tables (bad design, just for demonstrational purposes):

`documents`= `id`:int, `extension_type`: enum(Letter,Contract,Report), `extension_id`: int,`link`:text,`author`:`text`,`title`:`text`

`document_to_document` = `document_id`:int,`child_document_id`:int

`letters` = `extension_id`:int,`sender`,`recepient`

`contracts` = `extension_id`:int, `valid_until`,`additional_field_5`

`reports` = `extension_id`:int, `additional_field_6`

Comment: where is the the title in your fields?

Comment: Added it. It doesn't really makes too much difference to the question.